# How do I @mention people

Tags: support

I see linked people (hyperlinked name) mentioned here in StackExchange but I don't understand how to do it when posting. Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is only allowed in comments. There are a bunch of different rules behind it.

> **Replying in comments** The owner of the post you're commenting on will always be notified of your comment. If you are replying to
>   someone else who has previously commented on the same post, mention
>   their username: @peter and @PeterSmith will both notify a previous
>   commenter named “Peter Smith”.
>
> It is generally sufficient to mention only the first name of the user
>   whose comment you are replying to, e.g. @ben or @marc. However you may
>   need to be more specific if three people named Ben replied in earlier
>   comments, by adding the first character of the last name, e.g. @benm
>   or @benc Spaces are not valid in comment reply names, so don't use
>   @peter smith, always enter it as @peters or @petersmith.
>
> If the user you're replying to has no natural first name and last
>   name, simply enter enough characters of the name to make it clear who
>   you are responding to. Three is the minimum, so if you're replying to
>   Fantastico, enter @fan, @fant, or @fantastic.
>
> You can use the same method to notify any editor of the post, or – if
>   this is the case – to the ♦ moderator who closed the question.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020